# Getting a list of tagged services in my controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

What i want is to add services to the service container that i want to use later in my controller or service.

So i created two services with my custom tag **fbeen.admin**

here they are:

```
services:
    app.test:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\TestAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: fbeen.admin }

    fbeen.admin.test:
        class: Fbeen\AdminBundle\Admin\TestAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: fbeen.admin }
```

Now i want to use all the services with the tag fbeen.admin in my controller but i dont know how.

I followed the [How to work with service tags](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/service_container/tags.html) tutorial but i get stuck on this rule:

```
$definition->addMethodCall('addTransport', array(new Reference($id)));
```

On some way the addTransport method of the TransportChain class should be called but it seems that it isn't been called.

And even if it would be called then i still do not have a list of services with the fbeen.admin tag into my controller.

I am sure that i am missing something but who can explain me what it is?

p.s. I know that compilerPass runs at buildtime but for example sonata admin knows all admin classes and twig knows all twig extensions. How do they know?

Thank you for reading this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Symfony 3.3

Container gets compiled once (in debug more often, but in production only once). What you manage with `addMethodCall...` is that once you request your service from container, which you are storing in `$definition` (that in this case is controller). Then container will call method `addMethodCall('method'..` during initialising your service.

What it will look in container:

```
// This is pseudo content of compiled container
$service = new MyController();
// This is what compiler pass addMethodCall will add, now its your 
// responsibility to implement method addAdmin to store admins in for 
// example class variable. This is as well way which sonata is using
$service->addAdmin(new AppBundle\Admin\TestAdmin());
$service->addAdmin(new AppBundle\Admin\TestAdmin());

return $service; // So you get fully initialized service
```

## Symfony 3.4+

What you can do is this:

```
// Your services.yaml
services:
    App/MyController/WantToInjectSerivcesController:
        arguments:
            $admins: !tagged fbeen.admin

// Your controller
class WantToInjectSerivcesController {
    public function __construct(iterable $admins) {
        foreach ($admins as $admin) {
            // you hot your services here
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus autotagging of your services. Lets say all your controllers implements interface `AdminInterface`.

```
// In your extension where you building container or your kernel build method
$container->registerForAutoconfiguration(AdminInterface::class)->addTag('fbeen.admin');
```

This will tag automatically all services which implement your interface with tag. So you don't need to set tag explicitly.

Comment: The !tagged is available from Symfony 3.4+

Comment: Sorry, missed your symfony version, added explanation for 3.3

Answer (score 1):

The thing to note here is this: The CompilerPass doesn't run the 'addTransport' (or whatever you may call it) in the compiler-pass itself - just says 'when the time is right - run `$definition->addTransport(...)` class, with this data'. The place to look for where that happens is in your cache directory (`grep -R TransportChain var/cache/`), where it sets up the `$transportChain->addTransport(...)`.

When you come to use that service for the first time - only then is the data filled in as the class is being instantiated from the container.

Comment: Thank you Alister but now how to read the necessary data from the cache?

Comment: The calls to `addTransport()` (or whatever you wish to call it) will happen when the service is instantiated - when you use it via container->get(...) or auto-wired in a controller's constructor or service. and so the data would be available from wherever it was saved.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

extend the TransportChain class with a getTransports method:

```
public function getTransports()
{
    return $this->transports;
}
```

and use the TransportChain service in my controller:

```
use AppBundle\Mail\TransportChain;

$transportChain = $this->get(TransportChain::class);
$transports = $transportChain->getTransports();
// $transports is now an array with all the tagged services
```

Thank you **Alister Bulman** for pushing me forwards :-)